# Jumi plugin doesnt seem to load jQuery and images called with css in joomla 1.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I have a select list I have styled using html, css& js, it is working independently but once I load it into an article it displays the default html select list. I have tried positioning the customized select.html using Jumi plugin it loads most css but somehow refuses to load images called in the css. Help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the last time I used Joomla, it uses Mootools. Mootools and jQuery don't get along well because they fight over `$` namespace and most people use `$` in jQuery code.

to prevent this, you should either

- use [`$.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to change the jQuery namespace
- use `jQuery` instead of `$` in your code
- enclose your code in a closure:

  ```
  (function($){
      //use `$` safely in here
  }(jQuery))
  ```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response but av tried that already but it doesnt seem to work

Comment: @user1393460 are you sure that: you've got the right paths to the files? you've got the files loaded? what does the console say?

Comment: Yes the paths are all ok, the files are loaded but the console give an Error:$(document).ready is not a function

Comment: I think you didn't do the `.noConflict()` properly. The only way that it can't be a function is if something has overridden it, possibly Mootools.

Comment: The .noConflict() script is loaded I can even see it on page source. Another problem is background image called in css happen not to display. I trust it is not the jquery issue, is it?